# How to load test GraphQL API with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, graphql, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

I want to configure Jmeter to test the performance of following GraphQL API. I am unable to configure.

**API End Point :** https://graphqlzero.almansi.me/api

**Query :** `query:` {
user(id: 1) {
id
name
}
}``

Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to execute a [POST request](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) therefore you need to:

1. Add [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to your test plan and configure it like:

   [image]

   Textual representation of the body just in case:

   ```
   {
     "query": "{user(id: 1) {id name}}"
   }
   ```
2. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `application/json`

   [image]

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you have the call as a cURL command line, you can use menu:

> Tools > Import from curl

Otherwise:

- add Thread group
- add a Header Manager inside it with Content-Type set to application/javascript
- Add in it a Http Request, put in host the host name and in path the /api/

Comment: I have tried doing this but no happening. Can you please guide me in detail with my API url or attach some screenshot. I will be highly obliged.